# Training an ensemble of small neural networks efficiently in TensorFlow 2

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow, training, ensemble-modeling

I have a bunch of small neural networks (say, 5 to 50 feed-forward neural networks with only two hidden layers with 10-100 neurons each), which differ only in the weight initialization. I want to train them all on the same, smallish dataset (say, 10K rows), with a batch size of 1. The aim of this is to combine them into an ensemble by averaging the results.

Now, of course I can build the whole ensemble as one neural network in TensorFlow/Keras, like this:

```py
def bagging_ensemble(inputs: int, width: int, weak_learners: int):
    r'''Return a generic dense network model

    inputs: number of columns (features) in the input data set
    width: number of neurons in the hidden layer of each weak learner
    weak_learners: number of weak learners in the ensemble
    '''
    assert width >= 1, 'width is required to be at least 1'
    assert weak_learners >= 1, 'weak_learners is required to be at least 1'

    activation = tf.keras.activations.tanh
    kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.GlorotUniform()

    input_layer = tf.keras.Input(shape=(inputs,))
    layers = input_layer
    hidden = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=width, activation=activation, kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer)\
                (input_layer)
    hidden = []
    # add hidden layer as a list of weak learners
    for i in range(weak_learners):
        weak_learner = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=width, activation=activation, kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer)\
                        (input_layer)
        weak_learner = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid)(weak_learner)
        hidden.append(weak_learner)

    output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Average()(hidden)  # add an averaging layer at the end

    return tf.keras.Model(input_layer, output_layer)      

example_model = bagging_ensemble(inputs=30, width=10, weak_learners=5)
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(example_model)
```

The resulting model's plot looks like this:
[image: Plot of Keras model]

However, training the model is slow, and because of the batch size of 1, a GPU doesn't really speed up the process. How can I make better use of the GPU when training such a model in TensorFlow 2, without using a larger batch size?

[The motivation for using this kind of ensemble is the following: Especially with small datasets, each of the small networks will yield different results because of different random initializations. By bagging as demonstrated here, the quality of the resulting model is greatly enhanced. If you're interested in the thorough neural network modelling approach this technique comes from, look for the works of H. G. Zimmermann.]

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem with this approach, though I'm up for discussion about it and might be wrong.

Idea: You should train every sub-model on the main task, not the ensemble. For that, you can utilise your GPU to actually calculate everything in parallel (Even with a 5-dimensional input, effectively encoding 5 batches at once, further enhancing the independent training of the sub-models). To do this, my quick bet would be to just have five independent outputs, all optimised with a weight of 1/5th on the same loss you use for the averaging function. Then, do the averaging afterwards, without further optimisation.

Motivation: The fact that you have the averaging layer inside of the model as the output layer means, that the loss differentiation takes place there as well. This means, that during training, you allow interdependancies inbetween the single sub-networks. After short consideration it should be clear that this is not really what your motivation suggests:

> [The motivation for using this kind of ensemble is the following: Especially with small datasets, each of the small networks will yield different results because of different random initializations.

The small networks don't yield anything, because you don't measure and optimise for their yield. In short, you just built a bigger model with a slightly more complicated connectivity.

Comment: Training each of the small networks completely on its own is actually the most promising option I see, so I fully agree to that idea. I just  don't know how to do that in parallel in Keras/Tensorflow. Regarding the results of training the whole thing including the average: The resulting models is actually much better than a single small network, despite the interdependencies during training.

Comment: An additional remark: I tried to just get rid of the average and have 5 independent outputs instead, but that just slows training down instead of accelerating it.

Comment: @MightyCurious I see. The fact that "The resulting models is actually much better than a single small network, despite the interdependencies during training" is just another of those great new things we encounter when using Neural Nets in the real world!

Comment: @MightyCurious As for the SpeedUp/SlowDown with independent Model approach (averaging outside of the model): Did you consider the 5-dimensional Inputs? To rephrase: Let one Batch be of size (1, 5) instead of (1), then introduce Lambda Layers before each sub-model, that look like (Lambda x: x[:, n]) /n=1..5/ etc for each sub-model.
Should give 5-times performance, as you could reduce your dataset rows by factor 5.
**You will have to extract the weights afterwards and build a model with Batchsize (1), to get back to your initial use case.** But for training, this should work

Comment: This sounds good! I haven't tried that yet, but I will now.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you correctly -- your approach would mean that each of the small networks only sees one fifth of the training set, doesn't it?

Comment: @MightyCurious Yes, i justed realised ... This wouldnt really get you very far at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98279/discussion-between-simon-krannig-and-mightycurious).

Comment: Chat is a good idea; but unfortunately my WLAN blocks the chat, so I can't access it.